# BorderLayout.NORTH behaving unexpecedly

Tags: java, swing, layout, components, border-layout

I have a JFrame-descendant window a with a JMenuBar and two components stored in a JPanel. One is a JTabbedPane, which occupies the majority of the screen, and the other is small JPanel that in turn contains a series of buttons. They are constructed as such:

```
//in constructor:
menubar = new BFIDEMenuBar(this);

setJMenuBar(menubar);

content = new JPanel();
add(content);

buttons = new BFIDEButtonBar();

editors = new JTabbedPane();

content.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
content.add(editors, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When the window is smaller than a certain size, the components arranged as expected: the JTabbedPane occupying the center with the "buttons" JPanel centered above it:
[image: Looks good.]

However, if the window is re-sized beyond a certain threshold, the JPanel changes location:

[image: Not looking good.]

Shrinking the window causes it to jump back to its previous (correct) position.

I have read the [javadoc for BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and I have used it before, but I have yet to encounter this phenomenon. The javadoc says that "The NORTH and SOUTH components may be stretched horizontally;" but I don;t this counts as stretching.

No other methods are called from the constructor save for adding a few listeners and the obligatory `setVisible`, `setEnabled`, and the like.

Any thoughts on why this is happening or how to rectify it?

Comment: try `content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` instead of `content = new JPanel();`

Comment: @GnomezGrave MadProgrammer beat you to it. Thanks though.

Comment: Anyhow, you got the answer correct. (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JPanel` by default uses a `FlowLayout`.

Try using

```
content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

instead